# How to solve the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k^2\, e^{-ikx} dk$?

Tags: integration

How to solve the integral  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k^2\, e^{-ikx} dk$ ? this does not converge, please help.

Comment: Well, since it doesn't converge, in what sense are you hoping to "solve" it?

Comment: Well if you're a physicist or you're working with distributions, you can probably extend the definition of fourier transform and supposedly this one comes out to be something like $2\pi \delta '' (x)$ where $\delta (x)$ is the dirac delta function. I know how to get to this assuming a definition of a dirac delta function and using integration by parts.

Comment: I don't know, maybe using 1 + 1 dimension, I don't know if it's acceptable or applicable to the case

Comment: @snulty The Fourier transform of $k^2$ is certainly $2\pi\delta''$, or some such. That doesn't give the value of the integral! The integral simply doesn't exist; the Fourier transform I mention about is not that integral.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich would you not say that at least notationally that that integral could represent the Fourier transform of $k^2$, regardless of whether the integral as is is rigorously defined.

Comment: @snulty With $f_n(x)= \int_{-n}^n k^2 e^{-ikx}dk$ the sequence of smooth functions $f_n$ converges in the sense of distributions, to $2\pi \delta''(x)$

Comment: @all, yes. But isn't it $-2\pi \delta''(x)$ ?

Comment: Sure $-\int_{-n}^n e^{-ikx}dk$ converges to $-2\pi \delta(x)$, its 2nd derivative converges to $-2\pi\delta'(x)$